# Type predicate only working working properly after assignment

Tags: typescript

I have a type predicate method and a Type:

```
type TokenType = { categories: string[] }
const isToken = (token): token is TokenType => someBoolean
```

and I am using this somewhere in my code:

```
isToken(tokens[selected]) ? tokens[selected].categories : null
```

but I am getting: `Property 'categories' does not exist on type DifferentType`

However when I am doing this:

```
const test = tokens[selected]
isToken(test) ? test.categories : null
```

it works just fine.

Comment: The use of the type predicate does **not** narrow `tokens`. As you've seen, you need to extract a variable it _will_ narrow.